# Have Excel formulas that return 0, make the result blank

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

A recurring Excel problem I have is formulas such as `INDEX(array,row,column)` that return 0 when there's no result, rather than returning blank.

What is the best way to change the zero result to blank?

Here are approaches that I have tried so far:

1) Using division by zero. If INDEX returns 0, I cause an error that I then filter out.

```
=IFERROR(1/1/INDEX(A,B,C),"")
```

CONS: Makes the formula more messy and hides errors you may want to see.

2) Using custom formatting

```
0;-0;;@
```

CONS:
 
1) can't simultaneously apply date format
2) It doesn't work with conditional formatting when it comes to checking for blank cells (there is still the value of zero, it's just not shown)

3) Using`IF` statements

```
=IF((1/1/INDEX(A,B,C))<>"",(1/1/INDEX(A,B,C)),"")
```

CONS: Messy repetition

Does anyone have any other/better ideas?

Comment: No reason you can't exclude zero with date format - custom format like this for example - m/d/yy;;

Comment: Tristan, just out of interest, what sort of extra detail are you _looking_ for (based on your comment when setting the bounty)? My answer (and a few of the others) all seem to provide enough detail, as far as I can see, which would allow you to solve your problem. I even added detailed steps on how to create the macro and use it, in case that was what was causing you grief. If you think the answers are deficient somehow, tell us _why_ and we can fix them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create your *own* user defined functions in a module within Excel such as (from memory, so may need some debugging, and the syntax may vary among Excel versions as well):

```
Public Function ZeroToBlank (x As Integer) As String
    If x = 0 then
        ZeroToBlank = ""
    Else
        ZeroToBlank = CStr(x)
    End If
End Function
```

You can then simply insert `=ZeroToBlank (Index (a,b,c))` into your cell.

There's a nice tutorial on just this subject [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel).

The basic steps are:

- Open the VB editor within Excel by using `Tools -> Macro -> Visual Basic Editor`.
- Create a new module with `Insert -> Module`.
- Enter the above function into that module.
- In the cells where you want to call that function, enter the formula
       `=ZeroToBlank (<<whatever>>)`
  where `<<whatever>>` is the value you wish to use blank for if it's zero.
- Note that this function returns a string so, if you want it to *look* like a number, you may want to right justify the cells.

Note that there may be minor variations depending on which version of Excel you have. My version of Excel is 2002 which admittedly is pretty old, but it still does everything I need of it.

Comment: How do you prevent values that are actually "0" not to go blank?

Comment: @Gerhard, you simply use the value inside the function rather than the function, it's presumed you know what behaviour you want. If behaviour depends on _other_ factors, you can use `@if` or some other conditional control.

Answer (score 6):

The normal way would be the IF statement, though simpler than your example:

```
=IF(INDEX(a,b,c),INDEX(a,b,c),"")
```

No need to do gyrations with the formula, since zero values trigger the false condition.

Comment: Wouldn't that return `""` for cells that actually contain `0`?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure it works with all type of data but the only solution I found for the moment is to test if index returns blank:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(a,b,c)),"",INDEX(a,b,c))
```

The formula

```
=IF(INDEX(a,b,c),INDEX(a,b,c),"")
```

does not work with text

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the easiest way is to add the text formatting condition to the formula, with a `?` modifier. Thus:

`(formula to grab values)` becomes:

`text((formula to grab values),"?")`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re willing to cause all zeroes in the worksheet to disappear, go into “Excel Options”, “Advanced” page, “Display options for this worksheet” section, and clear the “Show a zero in cells that have a zero value” checkbox.  (This is the navigation for Excel 2007; YMMV.)

Regarding your answer (2), you can save a couple of keystrokes by typing `0;-0;` –– as far as I can tell, that’s equivalent to `0;-0;;@`.  Conversely, if you want to be a little more general, you can use the format `General;-General;`.  No, that doesn’t automagically handle dates, but, as Barry points out, if you’re *expecting* a date value, you can use a format like `d-mmm-yyyy;;`.

Answer (score 1):

The question may be why would you want it to act different from how it does right now? Apart from writing your own enveloping function or an alternative function in VBA (which will probably cause calculation speed reduction in large files) there might not be a single solution to your different problems.

Any follow up formula's would most probably fail over a blank thus cause an error that you would capture with `IFERROR()` or prevent by `IF(sourcecell<>"";...)`, if you would use the latter then testing for a zero is just the same amount of work and clutter. Checking for blank cells becomes checking for 0 valued cells. (if this doenst work for you please explain more specific what the problem is).

For esthetic purposes the custom formatting solution would be just fine.

For charts there might be an issue, which would be solved by applying it in the original formula indeed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple answer to this messy problem--the SUBSTITUTE function.  In your example above:

```
=IF((1/1/INDEX(A,B,C))<>"",(1/1/INDEX(A,B,C)),"")
```

Can be rewritten as follows:

```
=SUBSTITUTE((1/1/INDEX(A,B,C), " ", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, by concatenating an `EMPTY` string.

```
INDEX(tt_Attributes,MATCH([RowID],tt_Attributes[RowID],0),COLUMN(tt_Attributes[Long Description]) ) & ""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=if(b2 = "", "", b2)
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting (Home tab, styles section) and apply highlight cells rule (putting 0 in the Format cells that are equal to box) but select custom format then the Number tab.  Select Category custom and in the type box put:

0;-0;;@

Sounds complicated but is actually simple.

This gives the advantage that the cell looks empty but 0 is still the underlying value, so any formulas you use against that cell/selection will still see it as being numeric and saves on lots of messing around with chained IF statements.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me today, so I tried putting the 0 in quotes, as shown in the example below.

Example:
=IF(INDEX(a,b,c)="0","", INDEX(a,b,c))

Answer (score 0):

Just append an empty string to the end.  It forces Excel to see it for what it is.

For example:

```
=IFERROR(1/1/INDEX(A,B,C) & "","")
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this issue recently and it is frustrating that excel changes a blank string into a 0. I do not think that a formula should solve this issue because adding more logic to a complex formula may be cumbersome and might even end up breaking the original formula. I have two non formula options below.

If you want to keep the formulas in the cells and have them return 0 instead of "" use the following Click Path:

1. File
2. Options
3. Advanced

Scroll to "Display options for this worksheet:"

4. Deselect "Show a zero in cells that have zero value"

I also want to give a simple manual solution if you want to change a **value** (as opposed to a formula) from 0 to a blank string. This solution is better than Find and Replace because it will not replace a number like 101 with 11.

1. Select all of your data
2. On the data tab, click the filter logo

[image: The Filter Logo itself]

3. Click on the pick list of the column with the undesired 0(s) to select only rows with the value "0" (Make sure to only clear the contents of cells containing contents with the exact value 0!)

[image]

4. Select the data (which is only 0s), right click and select clear contents

The other data will remain if you used the filter properly and the back button is always there if something goes wrong. I understand option 2 is very manual and "unelegant" but it does successfully convert a 0 into a blank string and it may relieve a frustrated individual who does not want to use an if statement.

I personally learned something exploring this (very dry) excel issue today and I am personally using these methods moving forward. A quick macro of option 2 could be a good option if this is a frequent task for an intermediate excel user.

Answer (score -1):

`=IF(INDEX(a,b,c)="0","", INDEX(a,b,c))` worked for me with a minor modification. Excluding the 0 and no spaces in between quotations:
`=IF(INDEX(a,b,c)="","", INDEX(a,b,c))`