# Excel formula Iferror

Tags: excel, formula

I have a drop down list (data validation) that populates other cells using vlookup that pulls data from a separate worksheet. I'd like to include an error message if the field is blank like "No data entered". However, I am getting "0" instead. Here is the formula I used:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,6,FALSE),"No data entered")
```

I then changed this to an ISERROR:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,5,FALSE))=FALSE,"No data entered", VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,5,FALSE))
```

This gives the error message appropriately but now my drop down list does not populate the other cells!
What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Looking at your formulas, I see two noteworthy points:</strike>

1. in the IFERROR you return the 6th column, in the ISERROR, the 5th!
2. in the ISERROR, you show the error message when something is found, as you say `=IF(ISERROR=FALSE,ErrorMsg,...)`!
      To solve your problem, simply use this formula:

   ```
   =IF(ChildName="","No data    entered",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,6,0),"Cannot find    "&ChildName))
   ```

Ah, I see! Check out this question - [Have Excel formulas that return 0, make the result blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239466/have-excel-formulas-that-return-0-make-the-result-blank). It shows all ways.

My favorite is `=IFERROR(1/1/VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,6,0),"No data!")`. Only works with numbers though.

Else, use `=IF(VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,6,0),VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,6,0),"No data!")`.

To be on the safe side, this version should take care of all potential issues: `=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,6,0),VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,6,0),"No data!"),"No data!")`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The first point was just my cleaning up the formula so it's not that. The second point, however, is what made me think the drop down wasn't populating other cells-it actually still is but as you noted, because they have data, I didn't catch that.

Comment: I don't think your formula will work for me because I want the child name to appear in the drop down and then the vlookup to check different cells in another worksheet (not just childname).  So if a2 is empty, I want it to fill the cell with "No data" and if not empty, to fill in the value.  I have about 10 cells (A2-A12) that I want it to check. I feel the IsError is the closest but it's not populating when the cell is empty if I put =TRUE.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. So the user is supposed to enter A2 using a drop down - but if he enters nothing, it should be replaced with "No value"? The only way to do this without a macro is with a custom format `0,0,"No data",@`, but that will not be useful for any follow up formula.

Comment: I have a list of names Child1, Child2, Child3 in the drop down (data validation=ChildName). When one child is picked from the list (ChildName), I want the next 10 cells below it to populate with the child's information (DOB, Parent name, Date of Screen, etc.).  If for a particular child, there is no data for say, Date of Screen, for the selected child, I want that cell to say "No data entered".  If there is a date, the cell should populate with the date. And so on for the other cells. It is populating with the data but when no data, I get a "0".  Not sure why.

Comment: Ah, I see! Check out this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239466/have-excel-formulas-that-return-0-make-the-result-blank. it shows all ways. My favorite is `=IFERROR(1/1/VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,6,0),"No data!")`. Only works with numbers though. Else, use `=IF(VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,6,0),VLOOKUP(ChildName,Children,6,0),"No data!")`.

Comment: I still can't get the correct error message to appear even using these. The =IfERROR(1/1/... works great with the date cell if there is no data but does not work when there is data. The second one, =If(Vlookup.., comes very close working for both text and date cells if there is no data but does not work for the text when there is data--I get #VALUE!.  Not sure if you can help me further but wanted to document this. Thanks again for your help.